# bind the RadCombobox at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-combobox

I have a webpage which is buit on regular ASP.NET and I am using Telerik `ComboBox` in my `GridView`. I want to show dynamic data in my `ComboBox`. How can I write the code to bind the `RadComboBox` at `PageLoad` event in asp.net with dynamic?

Comment: I am not sure if i am doing right since  ia m very new to .net technologes .Here is what i have tried so far i have created a dynamic datatable and trying to inset data into combo box but i was struk on how to do it..thanks @ Konard

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way of binding data to RadCombobox.

Here are the examples -

[XML String Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/xmlstringbinding/defaultcs.aspx)

[Declarative DataSources](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/declarativedatasources/defaultcs.aspx)

[EntityDataSource](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/entitydatasource/defaultcs.aspx)

[LinqDataSource](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/linqdatasource/defaultcs.aspx)